# Change Paypal Express endpoint dynamically with php sdk

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the PHP Paypal merchant SDK.

Up to this point I have used the setting in the config file to set the endpoint. I'd like to be able dynamically change the end point in my code, so that when i'm running in development mode it will use the sandbox address, and when i'm running live mode it will use the product address.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Please use the php merchant sdk version 2.3.* and above. PayPal PHP SDKs have added support for dynamic configs and now you don't need config files for configuration. Please use the mode = "sandbox" or "live" to choose appropriate endpoints.

For additional info, please check README.md or samples available in the github repo

https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didn't see in the read me that you can set the constant PP_CONFIG_PATH to change the path to config file. That's what i did now i have to 2 config files. Worked perfectly!